# New Blender not Working with Animation Nodes

Tags: versions, animation-nodes

I have gotten the latest version of Blender (from Thomas' PPA), but it no longer works with Animation Nodes (any version of AN, 1.5 or older).

I get the error like I do not have numpy installed, but I do have Python Numpy installed and Python 3 Numpy. (I had this problem the first time I tried activating with older AN, but I have fixed it and have Python3 Numpy (and all the rest of Python3).

[image]

Getting out some of my older versions of Blender it works as well, like the 2.77 pre-release test build. It is only with the current version (Hash:22a2853, Date: 2016-03-18) that it doesn't work.

I downloaded the latest development build and it works as well. I think it's just this official build where it doesn't work.

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Please report this on github.

Comment: They updated the Python libs, so there might be a problem. Go and report it. ;-)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the problem though, because it works fine when I'm running out of a folder from the build bot, just not when I'm running off my actual computer (since 2.77)? So should I still report it?

Comment: Are there any weird Unicode characters in your folder path from where you are running Blender or python? Some times those cause problems when finding libraries

Comment: No. I wish I could say that's the problem, but I don't see any problems like that (no extra dots before the extension either).